# Javascript - On('Click') - Error - Calling On Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-on, clicklistener

```
<a href="#" class="audiocontrol"></a>
<a href="#" class="audiocontrol"></a>
<a href="#" class="audiocontrol"></a>
<a href="#" class="audiocontrol"></a>

<script>
    function playController(dataObj){
        alert(dataObj);
    }

    function playHandlers(){
        var dataObj = "stef";
        $('.audiocontrol').on('click', playController(dataObj));
    }

    $(document).ready(playHandlers);
</script>
```

This bit of code is firing off on page load whether I click the object or not. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
function playController(dataObj){
    alert(dataObj);
}

function playHandlers(){
    var dataObj = "stef";
    $('.audiocontrol').on('click', function() { playController(dataObj); } );
}

$(document).ready(playHandlers);
```

The way your code was written, it was calling `playController` when you were registering it in the `.on` call.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Awgyz/)

Answer (score 3):

You're invoking the function therefore passing the result of `playController`. You can do something like this.

```
function playHandlers(){
    var dataObj = "stef";

    $('.audiocontrol').on('click', function() {
        playController(dataObj);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:
(demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XEayq/))

```
function playController(dataObj) {
    alert(dataObj);
}

function playHandlers() {
    var dataObj = "stef";
    $('.audiocontrol').on('click', function () {
    playController(dataObj)
   });
}
$(document).ready(playHandlers);
```

This will load your code when the page loaded and call the function `playHandlers()`. You were calling it directly because you forgot to add `function(){}` in the on/click call.